# replacing a strings using simple_html_dom

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP to parsing the strings by using simple_html_dom.

The return strings I get is something like this:

```
<span id="title1">Reba"House Rules" (D) </span>
```

Here is the current PHP:

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}

    $links = $row['links'];
    $html = file_get_html($links);
    //echo $row['links'];

    $base = $row['links'];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $html->load($str);

    //get all category links
    /*foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $element->href );
        echo "</pre>";
    }*/

    //$html_base->clear();
    //unset($html_base);

    $time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1Time]', 0)->plaintext;
    $title1 = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext; // with this
    $output1 = preg_replace('/\d:\d+/', '', $title1);

    $html->clear();
    unset($html);


    echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - ';

    if (strstr($output1, '"'))
    {
      $output1 = str_replace('" ', '', $output1);
    }
?>
```

I have tried this:

```
$output1 = str_replace('" (D) ', '', $output1);
```

It will not let me to replace the strings i'm looking for.

I can only use something like this:

```
$output1 = str_replace('(D)', '', $output1);
```

Can you please tell me in what other way how I can check on the strings of what text I'm looking for before replacing them?

Comment: Can you please add the full contents of $str or atleast the parts being parse by $html->find. Also what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: Some 50 lines of code from here do nothing (db_connect()). Post the full contents of $str or point us to the page that contains it.

Comment: Perhaps there are no spaces, but instead `&nbsp;` Like `'"&nbsp;(D)&nbsp;'` or similar

Comment: @Colandus how I can check on the elements if they have a single quote with a space so I can replace them with a empty string?

Comment: I see no reason why your first attempt shouldn't work. However, why don't you just do as you do already and replace `'(D)'` only, and then use `trim` on `$output1`?

Comment: I can't, because I want to check on the end of the text to replace with a empty string. I have two double quotes in each element. e.g: <span id="title1">Million Dollar Listing New York"Look Me in the Eye" </span>

Comment: i want to make something like: <span id="title1">Million Dollar Listing New York: Look Me in the Eye</span>, how i can do that?